# (Cocos2d) how to implement optional sprites for a single scene & layer?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am sorry for the terrible description of this question. I am making a game where the user has to try and through a football through a moving tire. I have the game set up with a single scene & layer and I am wondering how to implement options for having different background images, tires, and footballs to choose from. I don't expect someone to explain to me how to code my game. I want to have specific objects for the different background images. Like, for instance, a prison background image would have a metal tire, different football, and have certain objects be flying through the scene while attempting to throw the football through the tire. Should I create a separate scene & layer for each background image & its corresponding sprites or is there a better way to go about this. All I am asking is for someone to point me to some example code or a project that does something similar. SORRY for the long post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to keep everything in just one png (background + moving sprites) and use a `CCSpriteBatchNode` you can easily keep the rects of the elements equal for all the different settings and just load a different file.

Otherwise just have a set of files and use same `CGRect`, it shouldn't be hard at all..

Comment: What do yo mean by a set of files?

Comment: Use a different batch of files, eg "bg1.png" "sprites1.png" and "bg2.png" "sprites2.png" and then keep the same coordinates for the elements but just switch the name whenever you load the `CCTexture2D7``